# Revert merges keeping resolutions

Tags: git, git-flow

In our team we are applying git flow without pull request, this is, each one of us develops features in their own branches that start in develop and once finished they get merged into develop. Our workflow is:

1. Pull develop
2. Branch feature/[name] from develop
3. Develop that feature in that branch
4. Go back to develop, pull develop
5. Merge the finished feature
6. Resolve possible conflicts
7. Push develop

However some times happens that two developers finish a feature at the exact same time. Now, imagine two developers have merge conflicts. The first one who pushes develop will update origin's develop, so when the other tries to push, it will fail, since they have diverged.

Now, we don't want the second developer pulling from develop and merging both... Because it breaks the "beauty" of having only one develop branch with features branching/merging from it but then have 2 develop branches. What we do now is reset local develop to origin/develop and repeat the merge/finish feature, but if the merge conflict was hard to resolve we have to do it again.

In a picture, we have this:
[image: Git graph]

I'd like to repeat that last merge, but with origin/develop without having to resolve manually the conflicts I had. I know I may have new merge conflicts, but I don't want to repeat the ones I have already resolved.

It looks like a rebase --preserve-merged, but that doesn't keep merge resolutions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rerere` is what you are looking for; when enabled, it remembers how you resolved merge conflicts, and when it sees the same conflicts, automatically resolves them for you. Enable it with `git config --global rerere.enabled true`. You can read more about it [here](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html).

Answer (score 2):

A tweak to your workflow should solve this problem.  Instead of merging `feature` into `develop`, rebase `feature` onto `develop`.  If `develop` creeps forward the work done to rebase the `feature` branch is still done: they only have to rebase on top of the new branch.  You're always trying to work on the tip of the `develop` branch.  This makes things much simpler.

Here's an example.  This is the state when both developers are ready to merge.  They've both updated `develop`.

```
A - B - F [origin/develop] [develop]
     \
      C - D - E [feature/1]

A - B - F [origin/develop] [develop]
 \
  Z - X - Y [feature/2]
```

They both `git rebase develop`.  (This will result in new commit IDs, but I'm taking the liberty in these diagrams of reusing the same IDs to show the continuity of commit content).

```
         [origin/develop] [develop]
A - B - F - C - D - E [feature/1]

         [origin/develop] [develop]
A - B - F - Z - X - Y [feature/2]
```

In order to preserve the existence of the branch in history, they both do a merge but with `--no-ff`. `git checkout develop; git merge --no-ff feature/X`  This doesn't actually merge, but forms a nice feature bubble which is useful for later code archaeology to understand which series of commits was done together as a single feature.

```
         [origin/develop]
A - B - F - C - D - E [feature/1] [develop]
        \          /
         ----------

         [origin/develop]
A - B - F - Z - X - Y [feature/2] [develop]
         \          /
          ----------
```

Then they both push, but the first dev gets there first.  The second one has their push rejected and so the second dev updates `develop`.

```
A - B - F - C - D - E [feature/1] [origin/develop] [develop]
        \          /
         ----------

          Z - X - Y [feature/2]
         /
A - B - F - C - D - E [origin/develop] [develop]
        \          /
         ----------
```

No problem, the second dev repeats the procedure.  They rebase onto `develop`.  This only requires resolving conflicts with the new commits from `feature/1`.

```
A - B - F - C - D - E - Z - X - Y [feature/2] 
        \          /  [origin/develop] [develop]
         ----------
```

Then `git checkout develop; git merge --no-ff feature/2; git push`.

```
                      ---------
                     /         \
A - B - F - C - D - E - Z - X - Y [feature/2]
        \          /              [origin/develop] [develop]
         ----------
```

And finally both developers delete their local branches.  The history bubble and merge points will preserve their information for historical use.

Here's the process.

1. Update `develop`.

   - `git checkout develop`
   - `git pull --rebase`
2. Rebase feature onto `develop`.

   - `git checkout feature`
   - `git rebase develop`
3. Create an artificial merge point.

   - `git checkout develop`
   - `git merge --no-ff feature`
4. Push `develop`.
5. Delete `feature`.

Steps 1 to 3 can be safely repeated during the `feature` development process to keep `feature` up-to-date with what everyone else is pushing.

[Here is a blog post further illustrating this technique](http://www.bitsnbites.eu/?p=221).

Comment: That's a really interesting workflow, basically because it naturally """remembers""" merge conflicts because they have already been resolved, in fact, it doesn't actually redo those merge conflicts because they just won't happen again. However, resolving conflicts through rebase is slower and harder than through a simple merge... That's why by now I will use David's answer (use git rerere) to check if it works (it looks more messy and error-prone than your solution, but seems easier for end-users)

Comment: @olivarra1 The workflow has benefits beyond simply making merging easier. It makes it much easier to understand the history of the project. Dealing with conflicts while rebasing can be easier or it can be harder than in a merge, it depends on the type of conflict. At least with a rebase conflict you can deal with them one commit at a time. Overall, it encourages feature branches to never drift too far from their upstream so conflicts can't get too bad.